# How to allow only three numbers before a decimal point and two numbers after it. Is there a regex for this?

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

Only numbers between 0.00 and 100.00 can be allowed. The number can also be without decimal point.
I am trying to use this regex,

```
/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,?[0-9]{3}){0,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

But this allows more than 3 numbers before decimal point.
Trying to use the regex in ng-pattern of angular js.

Comment: Try `/^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|100(?:\.0{1,2})?)$/`, see https://regex101.com/r/wanOHb/1

Comment: I've resolved this by using min(set to 0) max(set to 100) of angular and little change in regex - /^[0-9]{0,2}(?:,?[0-9]{3}){0,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/